# Azure app-gateway failover when default backend pool is unhealthy

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

I have the following setup in AzureRM.

```
                                                ----------  
-----------     ----------     -----------      |app srv1|
| App     |     | Varnish|     | Load    | ---> ----------
| Gateway | --> | Cache  | --> | Balancer|  
|         |     | server |     |         | ---> ----------     
-----------     ----------     -----------      |app srv2|
                                                ----------
```

I would like to direct all requests to the Varnish server by default, but if Varnish dies, direct them directly to the Load Balancer.

I read that failover can be achieved with custom probes in the app gateway, but if I add the Load Balancer into the backend pools, if my thinking is right I believe it will do Round-Robin between the Varnish and the LB.

The reason to have the App Gateway is to offload the SSL cert.

Is it possible to achieve this infrastructure with Azure services?

Comment: We have precisely the same setup and the same issue :) In the end, did having redundant Varnish instances worked for you? Did they have their own cache? Or did you find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately today there isnt an easy way to achieve this. Failover pool is not supported yet. Your understanding is right that if you add LB to backend pool and it responds to health probes, Gateway will round-robin between Varnish and LB. One roundabout way could be to have another server which by default fails probe so requests arent routed to it. If the primary Varnish server fails, then this server should start responding with 200 OK to probes. This would require extra code to set up this secondary server which monitors Varnish and responds to probes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.
I ended up adding a second varnish server to have redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

(I know that I come "a bit" late after the battle, but just in case it could be someone else than me ^^)

As said by @amsriva-msft, to date, it isn't possible to do this kind of failover between two backend pools with App Gateway.

BUT in listener configuration, you can configure error page URLs, in order to redirect to a specific page instead of 502 errors (which is the code returned when all resources in backend pool are unavailable) :
**screenshot of error page URLs in App Gateway Listener configuration**

[image]
And instead of a classic error page, you could image putting an URL with DNS pointing to you load balancer as a 502 error page. Logically, I imagine this could only work with a single-page application as failover, because each request will be routed to the same URL.

EDIT: here is the procedure in MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error